# azure bicep deploy custom domain conflict

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I am deploying azure front door using bicep. It is erroring out

We couldn't create your custom domain. Another custom domain with the same host name already exists

we cannot delete the existing domains because we already added the _dnsauth record

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete the existing domains because we already added the _dnsauth record?**

Yes, we can delete existing domain associations first; later, we'll need to update TXT records on the provider's DNS side with the new domain. If we add without specifying a CNAME, we will receive this message.

**A CNAME record for '**.com' that points to '**.azurefd.net' could not be found. Before you can associate a domain with this Front Door, you need to create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for 'chfrontdrtestdemo.com' that points to '**.azurefd.net'.**

**is there a way around this?**

Yes, we have a workaround. First, we need to delete the existing domain association, and later we need to add a new CNAME entry. After that, we need to add the new domain association along with the txt entry mentioned below.

Step1:
Delete the existing domain association from Front Door [image]

Step2:
Add new domain association and register the same with DNS provider..
[image]

NOTE:
During the domain validation process. If "Validation state" is "Pending" and when we click on that link, it turns into "**Validate the custom domain**." The panel gives the information for the DNS record required in order to validate the domain. It's a TXT record for _dnsauth.****>.****>.com with a specific record value. We should register this TXT record value at the DNS provider; otherwise, it won't be successful.

Comment: I am using bicep for infrastructure as code solution. It would seem that we should be able to declare the custom domain in bicep and the deployment would be idempotent

Comment: I deleted and re added the custom domain. the deploy works and the redeploy works as well. I am still confused on why the bicep was trying to re add the custom domain, but its working now. Thanks