# bicep azure front door deploy what-if does not show custom domain changes

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code, azure-front-door

If I add a new custom domain to the azure cdn profile ( azure front door premium )  then run the --what-if I do not see any changes to the front door.

how do I get the what-if to give me ALL the changes the deploy will make ?
I added this new custom domain

```
resource customDomainNew 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customdomains@2022-05-01-preview' = if (customDomainDeploy) {
  parent: frontdoorProfile
  name: 'new-${baseDomainName}'
  properties: {
    hostName: 'new.${baseDomain}'
    tlsSettings: {
      certificateType: 'ManagedCertificate'
      minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS12'
    }
  }
}
```

then added `customDomainNew` to a route

```
resource frontdoorendpointFrontEnd 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdendpoints/routes@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  parent: frontdoorEndpointDefault
  name: 'frontend-v2'
  properties: {
    customDomains: [
      { id: customDomainApp.id }
      { id: customDomainNew.id } 
    ]
    ...
```

then I run the --what-if

`az deployment sub create -l eastus -f ./main.bicep -p ./Parameters/ci.json -w`

and I do not see any information about a new custom domain being added to the route , I only see tags that are changing. I also wonder why resources are ignored like `rontdoor-shared-ci-global`

```
PS /Users/user/Projects/Code/Cloud/Infrastructure>  az deployment sub create -l eastus -f ./main.bicep -p ./Parameters/ci.json -w
Note: The result may contain false positive predictions (noise).
You can help us improve the accuracy of the result by opening an issue here: https://aka.ms/WhatIfIssues

Resource and property changes are indicated with these symbols:
  + Create
  ~ Modify
  = Nochange
  * Ignore

The deployment will update the following scopes

Scope: /subscriptions/xxx

  ~ resourceGroups/rg-appservice-hats-ci-eastus [2022-09-01]
    ~ tags.deploymentTime: "14:36" => "14:42"

  ~ resourceGroups/rg-frontdoor-shared-ci-global [2022-09-01]
    ~ tags.deploymentTime: "14:36" => "14:42"

  ~ resourceGroups/rg-network-shared-ci-eastus [2022-09-01]
    ~ tags.deploymentTime: "14:36" => "14:42"

Scope: /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-appservice-hats-ci-eastus

  ~ Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/serverfarm-hats-ci-eastus [2022-03-01]
    ~ tags.deploymentTime: "14:36" => "14:42"

  ~ Microsoft.Web/sites/site-hats-ci-eastus [2022-03-01]
    + properties.siteConfig.localMySqlEnabled:   false
    + properties.siteConfig.netFrameworkVersion: "v4.6"
    ~ tags.deploymentTime:                       "14:36" => "14:42"

  = Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/private-endpoint-web [2021-02-01]
  * Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/private-endpoint-web.nic.xxxx

Scope: /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-frontdoor-shared-ci-global

  * Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/frontdoor-shared-ci-global
  * Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/frontdoor-shared-ci-global/afdendpoints/frontdoor-shared-ci-global
  * Microsoft.Network/frontdoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/wafsharedciglobal

Scope: /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-network-shared-ci-eastus

  ~ Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-shared-ci-eastus [2022-05-01]
    ~ tags.deploymentTime: "14:36" => "14:42"

Resource changes: 6 to modify, 1 no change, 4 to ignore.
```

you can see the what-if is not really providing that much detail.

Comment: Could you please mention any error / output screenshot for further research.  Hope this is relates to another thread which i worked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224580/azure-bicep-deploy-custom-domain-conflict

Comment: thank you for your input. I updated the question to include the changes. I have a hard time seeing anything useful in the what-if output. Is there a better way to get more data from the what-if? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my view there will be an issue with template, refer official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.cdn/profiles/customdomains?source=recommendations&pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

```
resource <resource Name>
'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customDomains@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 'string'
  parent: <Resource Name>
  properties: {
    azureDnsZone: {
      id: 'string'
    }
    extendedProperties: {}
    hostName: 'string'
    preValidatedCustomDomainResourceId: {
      id: 'string'
    }
    tlsSettings: {
      certificateType: 'string'
      minimumTlsVersion: 'string'
      secret: {
        id: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What-If compare our ARM template to the deployed service, based on the result, can decide if need to deploy. It's the same as the "terraform plan" command in terraform

here is the sample [tutorial](https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/11/09/using-what-if-to-optimize-arm-template-deployments/).  i have found couple of useful blogs related to [whatif](https://thingsandcode.com/2022/01/06/how-to-use-azure-what-if-command-to-validate-changes-before-deploying-an-arm-template/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be something with the main bicep as the results do not seem to include the sub-resources like custom domain and route. I would expect them to be listed in the scope of the FD RG.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).